# Запрос к базе

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails

Приветствую!

Интересует такой вопрос. В приложении ruby on rails использую mongodb в связке с mongoid.
Из вьюхи со списком пользователей пытаюсь перейти к странице выплат любого из пользователей. Соответственно при этом передаю `user_id`, ссылка выглядит как `payments/34a36c66f7a76c89f/show_out`
но перед тем как получить эти параметры в экшене контроллера payments, mongoid почему-то решает что ему нужно сделать запрос вида `Payment.find(user_id)` соответственно выдается ошибка так как в _id списка выплат он не может найти переданный id пользователя

`Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound in PaymentsController#show_out`

Таки не пришедший user_id пытаюсь обработать таким методом:

```
def show_out
        @payment_items = Payment.where(user_id: params[:id]).all
end
```

Может быть кто-то встречался с этим, либо я что-то упускаю, буду благодарен ответам! Если нужно показать еще какой-то код, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это лучше всего вынести в скоуп, ну да ладно.

```
@payment_items = Payment.where(user_id: params[:id].to_s)
```